# Export from Excel to SQL: Login Failed for User

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, connection-string

I'm trying to create a function within Excel that will write data to my remote SQL Server database with a click of a button. However, I keep getting an error telling me that that my login failed for user "UserName" (Error 80040e4d).

At first I thought there must be a problem with my User/Login within the database, so I went to the remote desktop, opened SQL Server Management Studio and checked all my permissions, made sure Windows authentication was selected, checked the password etc... Still didn't work.

My User has been given Read and Write permissions, so I tried to import data into Excel from SQL, which did work. So I'm assuming this must be an issue within my VBA code, more specifically, my connection string.

I would appreciate it if someone could take a look over it, and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or if someone else has had this issue and knows what's causing it?

Here's the code I have:

```
Sub Button3_Click()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim iRowNo As Integer
Dim sArtistId, sForename, sSurname, sNationality, sBirthDate, sDeathDate As String

With Sheets("NewArtist")

    'Open a connection to SQL Server
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=tcp:IPADDRESS,1433\SqlServer2008;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=PassWord" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    'Skip the header row
    iRowNo = 2

    'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
    Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        sCustomerId = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
        sFirstName = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
        sLastName = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)

        'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
        conn.Execute "insert into dbo.Components (ArtistId, Forename, Surname, Nationality, BirthDate, DeathDate) values ('" & sArtistId & "', '" & sForename & "', '" & sSurname & "', '" & sNationality & "', '" & sBirthDate & "', '" & DeathDate & "')"

        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox "Artists imported."

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

End With

End Sub
```

Thank you very much!

TW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integrated Security=SSPI`

this parameter in your connection string means you are going to pass your windows principal name as authentication, so the sql login and password are being ignored.

you should remove this name/value pair from the connection string, if you want to use a specified username and password.

Comment: It worked (Well something imported, not quite what I wanted, but that I can fix)! You are my new favourite person!! Thank you!

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept by ticking my answer ;-)